# Failed user login on production server using Symfony framework (Authentication request could not be processed due to...)

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, doctrine

I'm using Symfony for a project and I have been trying to get the login to work on production server with no success for the past 2 days. I keep getting the error

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

I have followed the guide here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) to setup loading users from database.

My **security.yml** file:

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Acceptme\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                patricia:
                    password: patricia
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    users:
        name: user_provider
        entity: { class: AcceptmeUserBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    user_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login_route
            check_path: _login_check
            default_target_path: homepage
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    default:
                anonymous: ~
                http_basic: ~

access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My **SecurityController.php:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
 * @Template("security/login.html.twig")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return array(
        'last_username' => $request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="_login_check")
 */
public function securityCheckAction()
{
    // this controller will not be executed,
    // as the route is handled by the Security system
}
}
```

I have tried uploading the project on 2 different web hosts (FatCow & GoDaddy) and the problem remains. Locally i am using PHP 5.4.19 (FatCow uses 5.3.2 and GoDaddy uses 5.4.37). Keep in mind that when working on localhost with XAMPP everything works fine!

I've confirmed that PDO is enabled in both cases. I've confirmed that the database username, password and host are correct in the **parameters.yml** file. Error logs on both local and remote servers show nothing.

I have followed all directions from this previous post [Deploying Symfony2 app getting fosuserbundle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors) and still no success.

Comment: Anything in logs (`app/logs/prod.log`) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors does solutions listed here help?

Comment: @ClémentBERTILLON Wow thank you so much. Most obvious place to looked and I kept missing it, frustration takes over. Yes i;ve found the issue now. Issue was that a sql coundt find a table because it was named incorrectly in the entity (with upper case letter) while the database table was lower case. Updating the answer for this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE: Issue solved. The issue was that a table in the entity php file was named with upper case letters while the database table was named with lower case. +1 to ClémentBERTILLON for pointing in the right direction, namely prod.log

Comment: prod.log saved me as well, got a different issue than the one in the question though. Mine was related to `max_allowed_packet` size. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like that the error:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

is too generic and does not tell anything about where the problem is (there is an issue opened about this matter [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16272)).

I solved my issue by checking the logs and see what happened (in `var/logs/dev.log`), hoping this helps someone.

In my specific case, there was a wrong parameter in parameters.yml about database connection. But, again, the error is too generic and does not necessarily imply that the problem is related with database connection.

Answer (score 11):

This problem can be fixed running command: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Answer (score 4):

AS @ShinDarth mention it. It is too generic and log inspection will help people in our case to get throught this.

If it can help in my situation it was :

After an SonataUserBundle installation in SF3, I had to

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

My context is particular, I have had already installed and used FOSUserBundle before to install SonataUserBundle. (Because of SF3 compatibility with FOSUser/SonataUSer...
Database have been taken 16 queries after that. Working great.

Answer (score 3):

You probably used the template given by Symfony docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) :

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Which actually gives you this error message. The most simple and reliable way to fix this issue is to replace this line by the following :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</div>
```

Which will give you the full stack-trace for your error and (hopefully) help you debug your application. Don't forget to revert this before going to production!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I changed user entity and then I forgot to update table.

for table update:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is a bug in Symfony and on production IF during authentication system error occurs (missing table, missing column or any other exception) - it's logged as INFO instead of ERROR and with default error logging options it's not logged at all.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/28462

I think there are two options right now - temporary log everything (including INFO) on production until you find the real error.

Second option: use this patch or debug directly on production.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that this error is too generic. In my case, The follow is incorrect:

```
class: App/Entity/User;
```

Correction:

```
class: App\Entity\User;
```

Comment: Similar here, in `security.yaml` one of the classes didn't exist. I recommend check every class like User, Provider, Encoder that it is loaded and provided by user.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is correct for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782535/2400373

But If you do not have access to the terminal, you can enter the server and delete the folders that are inside `var/cache`.

Another solution if you have access to the console is to type

```
#rm -rf var/cache/*
```

or

```
$sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
```

this solution works on symfony 3

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was fixed by correcting a typo in connection details in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause could be **MySQL Server**. In my case I forgot to start **MAMP / MySQL Server** and Symfony resulted with this message.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug on Symfony 5.3 that happens only on the Internet server. On my local server, no problem.  Try to downgrade to 4.5 or 5.0. Then try the authentication again. In my case, the token to authenticate the user can't create and is unable to make a query to the database to validate that the user password is correct.

Comment: If this is really a bug, can you share more details? Did you report it to Symfony to get it fixed? There is no version 4.5 you could downgrade to. Also, how could this only happen on the "Internet server"?

Answer (score 0):

To extend on answer given by gogaz, Symfony's security bundle doesn't seem to be logging these errors by default as (I guess) it's assumed they will be authentication issues.

It might be worth it to inject a logger into your action and (conditionally) log the errors.

```
public function loginAction(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, LoggerInterface $logger): Response
{
    if (($error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()) && ($error instanceof AuthenticationServiceException)) {
        $logger->critical($error->getMessage(), $error->getTrace());
    }

    ...
}
```

Do note that you might have to extend the logging if your security implementation can throw other error types you may want to log.