# Failed user login on symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to build a login system that checks my database `User` entity in order to authenticate.

My `security.yaml`:

```
providers:
    db_web:
      entity:
        class: AppBundle:User
        property: username
```

My `loginController` function is from the documentation:

```
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('/login/index.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

and the error I'm getting:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

Comment: Check your logs at var/log/dev.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed user login on production server using Symfony framework (Authentication request could not be processed due to...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519901/failed-user-login-on-production-server-using-symfony-framework-authentication-r)

Comment: `php bin/console cache:clear` helped me

Answer (score 0):

class in providers should have quotes around class name `class: "AppBundle:User"` instead of `class: AppBundle:User`.

[YAML validator](http://www.yamllint.com/)