# Clear Cache on Elastic Beanstalk using EB CLI

Tags: symfony, caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have the same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors).

I have a web app deployed on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk it was ok at first but when I uploaded a new version the authentication is now not working. I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors) and I checked everything related to the database such as username, password and whatnot. The only thing remaining that I havent check is the cache. I have no Idea how to clear it.

I installed `EB CLI` and be able to run my app correctly. But my question is how to I clear the cache on the beanstalk(?) and can I do it using the `EB CLI`?

I have no idea. Please help. Thank you. \m/

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Which cache are you talking about?

Comment: @Tal Im having the same problem as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors I suspect its because of the cache.

Comment: @RohitBanga The cache on the side of EB.