# Authentication error Symfony 4 login system

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I get the following error after submitting my login form:

```
Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.
```

I have written the following code:

**User Controller**

```
/**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('user/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
```

**Login.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block body %}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    encoders:
          App\Entity\User:
              algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        db_provider:
                    entity:
                        class: App\Entity\User
                        property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: true
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: db_provider
            form_login:
              login_path: login
              check_path: login

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**User entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt and argon2i algorithms don't require a separate salt.
        // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
        return null;
    }


    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }
}
```

In the profiler I can't find any logs telling me how to fix this issue. There are only two logs in info & errors:

Matched route "login". and Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.

Could anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: if you check in `app/logs/dev.log`, is there anything?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your database. Is the connection to your database ok? Is the schema up-to-date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying Symfony2 app getting fosuserbundle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135572/deploying-symfony2-app-getting-fosuserbundle-errors)

Comment: Most probably your `login_path` and `check_path` must be different URL paths. You can have a look at the [SecurityBundle Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) for more info. Let me know if this solves your issue so I can post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because I did load/install the wrong php database module:
- mysqli
- pdo-mysql
Did you select the correct one?